# React Native: how to customize the popup menu?

Tags: react-native, popupmenu

I am using an API of popup menu for React Native :

https://github.com/instea/react-native-popup-menu/blob/master/doc/api.md

But got stuck here :

My idea is ,the menu should popup ,when the user click the View of the menu .However ,I have tried so many times ,added Pressable etc ,still not working ..it works only when you clik the "5" in the View as below :

[image]

Could you please help me modify my code ? Thank you so much in advance !!

```
<Pressable style={styles.pickerContainer} onPress={()=>MenuProvider.open}>
    <Menu>
      <MenuTrigger text='5' />
      <MenuOptions>
      
        <MenuOption onSelect={() =>console.log("save")}>
        <Text style={{color: 'red'}}>save</Text>
        </MenuOption>
  
        <MenuOption onSelect={() => console.log("delete")} >
          <Text style={{color: 'red'}}>delete</Text>
        </MenuOption>
        <MenuOption onSelect={() => console.log("not call")}  text='Disabled' />
      </MenuOptions>
    </Menu>
    </Pressable>
```

Comment: keep style={{width: 50}} in MenuTrigger so it'll become the view tag

Comment: Hi @JohnOcean ,thank you so much for your suggestion ,I have tried ,it is not allow to do so ... Appears error "Type '{ text: string; style: { width: number; }; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<Component<MenuTriggerProps, any, any>> & Readonly<...> & Readonly<...>'.
  Property 'style' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & "